# Genesis framework : how to display the primary sidebar manually?

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

I need to display the primary sidebar in my Home.php template. What is the code to achieve this ?

Comment: To whomever downvoted: it's more useful if you also leave a comment explaining why you downvoted the question, so the person asking it can improve their question, or at least improve future questions.

Answer (score 1):

With `genesis_widget_area('sidebar');` you can have the primary sidebar appear on your homepage. As found in `genesis/lib/functions/widgetize.php`

Comment: Can you please provide more detail?